# jQuery - Input change event not firing on mobile / iPhone / iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple calculator which works fine on desktop, it updates automatically as you are changing the values of the input. The issue that I am having is that it doesn't work on iPhone / iPad, just seems it's not firing. Any ideas on how to correct this?

**HTML**

```
<label for="beer-lines">Number of beer lines</label>
<br>
<input type="text" value="10" id="beer-lines" class="savings-calc" name="beer-lines">
<br>
<br>
<label for="pints-line">Number of pints pulled through when cleaning each line</label>
<br>
<input type="text" value="3" id="pints-line" class="savings-calc" name="pints-line">
<br>
<br>
<label for="pints-one">Price for one pint</label>
<br>
<input type="text" value="3.5" id="pints-one" class="savings-calc" name="pints-one">
<br>
<br>
<span id="savings-total">£<span id="value">4095.00</div></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.savings-calc').bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event) {
        var price = 0;
        var default_cost = 39;
        var beer_lines = $('#beer-lines').val();
        var pints_line = $('#pints-line').val();
        var pints_one = $('#pints-one').val();

        var total = (default_cost * beer_lines * pints_line * pints_one).toFixed(2);

        $('#savings-total #value').text(total);
    });

});
```

**CODEPEN**

https://codepen.io/silvawebdesigns2020/pen/GRJPxWE

Comment: instead of `.bind` use `.on` or `.live`

Comment: I'm already using `.bind`, `.live` didn't work either

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie - Check here, it's not working mate: https://ding.org.uk/savings-calculator/

Comment: this not working even on desktop mate

Comment: you have `jQuery is not defined` error on your page. correct it first and it will work fine everywhere

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie - There are no errors defined on the page, please recheck

Comment: kindly open browser developer tool window(f12 for most browser) and check it's console tab